# Lining up <Image> in Silverlight leaves a line between the images - How to get rid of it?

Tags: silverlight, image

I'm trying to line up `<Image>`s in a Canvas based on absolute positioning, but the images always have a border around them. Is there anyway to get rid of it?

In this example, I have one picture called "yellow.png" that is 135h x 180w and I'm trying to place it like tiles in the Canvas. Here's the code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Black" Width="720" Height="540">
    <Canvas Width="720" Height="540">
        <Image Source="yellow.png" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"/>
        <Image Source="yellow.png" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="135" Width="180" Height="135"/>
        <Image Source="yellow.png" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="270" Width="180" Height="135"/>
        <Image Source="yellow.png" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="405"/>
        <Image Source="yellow.png" Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="0"/>
        <Image Source="yellow.png" Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="135"/>
        <Image Source="yellow.png" Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="270"/>
        <Image Source="yellow.png" Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="405"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

And here's how it looks:
[image]

Any thoughts on how i can get rid of the line between the images (so that it looks like it's just a single picture of those yellows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man, after tons of troubleshooting, I figured out that this only occurs on IE9 Beta. All other browsers that RTM works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Silverlight, but in earlier versions of IE we sometimes had to cram all the image tags together on the same line to overcome issues like this. Perhaps Silverlight has a similar hiccup?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce this.  I created a 180 × 135 image in Paint, coloured it solid yellow, saved it as 'yellow.png' and stuck it in a `Grid` using the same XAML as above.  There were no obvious grid lines at all.

Are you absolutely sure that your 'yellow.png' image is completely yellow, all the way to the edges?